# How to update react state from react-select multi?

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-select, react-state-management

I am learning to react and trying to update react state based on selected elements. I am using react-select. It's show all of the data right now. But i want to update the data when i select option from the select box. If i select multiple options,then it should update the state filtering the selected options.

```
const reviews = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "rating": 5,
    "label": [
      "Sports",
      "Sleep"
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "rating": 5,
    "label": [
      "Sports",
      "Pain"
    ],
  },
];
class SelectCreateFilter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    multi: null,
    data: reviews,
    health: healthBenefitsOptions,
    category: productCategoryOptions, 
    products: productOptions,
  };
  handleChange = name => value => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      data: this.state.data.filter() //how to perform the data mathcing to reviews.label
    });

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Select
            options={groupedOptions}
            components={components}
            value={multi}
            onChange={this.handleChange('multi')}
            placeholder="Select multiple tags or products for reviews"
            isMulti
            isSearchable
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping.
Here is the code from codesandbox so that you can check the above code
https://codesandbox.io/embed/jlro0vo4n3?fontsize=14

Comment: Can you please include relevant code and specify exactly what the problem is? One of the files on your sandbox is 300 lines long.

Comment: Thanks Nick..In app.js i have setup the sate like this
    state = {
    multi: null,
    data: reviews,
    health: healthBenefitsOptions,
    category: productCategoryOptions,
    products: productOptions
  };
   handleChange = name => value => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      data: 
    });
  };

I want to update the state data for handlechange event matching the selected options with data.label

Comment: Can you set up a reproducible example of your issue on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need you can make different filter strategy:

If you want to render the reviews that at least has one of the selected values in it's label, you would use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
  handleChange = name => values => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      [name]: values,
      data:
        values.length > 0  // if at least one value selected
          ? reviews.filter(review => // go through all reviews
              values.some(value => review.label.indexOf(value.label) >= 0) // and see if at least one selected value is in the label of that review
            )
          : reviews // if no value selected, show them all
    }));
  };
```

If you want to render the reviews that must have all of the selected values, you would use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
  handleChange = name => values => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      [name]: values,
      data:
        values.length > 0
          ? reviews.filter(review => 
              values.every(value => review.label.indexOf(value.label) >= 0) // check if every selected value is in a row
            )
          : reviews
    }));
  };
```

Comment: you did the right things i expected. I am going to mark it as the right solutions though i haven't tested it yet. But the logic is clear. Many thanks